# Typedef Function Syntax

Tags: c, function, variables, typedef

I have the following `typedef` function prototype:

`typedef void (*sa_sigaction_t)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);`

I have no idea how to use it. I understand that `(int, siginfo_t *, void*)` is `typedef`-ed into `sa_sigaction_t`. But how would I use it? These are all return types with no variable names specified.

So I assume I want to create a variable: `sa_sigaction_t handler`. How would I use it? The syntax is quite confusing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that (int, siginfo_t *, void*) is typedef-ed into sa_sigaction_t.

Actually no. `sa_sigaction_t` is a pointer to a function that returns `void` and takes `(int, siginfo_t *, void *)` as parameters.

So if you have:

```
void foo(int, siginfo_t*, void*)
{
}
```

you can do:

```
sa_sigaction_t fooPtr = &foo;
```

and then call it like this:

```
fooPtr(0,NULL,NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `typedef` in this case is sort of a short hand for a function which returns `void` and takes 3 arguments (`int`, `siginfo_t *` and `void *`). This is mainly useful for if you want to pass a function around as a callback for example.

```
void func1(sa_sigaction_t handler)
{
  handler(...);
}
```

`func1` invokes any function of type `sa_sigaction_t`. You can call it like so:

```
void func2(int a, siginfo_t * b, void * c)
{
  ...
}

int main(void)
{
  func1(func2);

  /*
   * Equivalent to:
   * sa_sigaction_t handler = func2;
   * func1(func2);
   */
  return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, if you did not have the `typedef`, your code would be more verbose:

```
void func1(void(*handler)(int, siginfo_t *, void*))
{
  handler(...);
}

void func2(int a, siginfo_t * b, void * c)
{
  ...
}

int main(void)
{
  func1(func2);

  /*
   * Equivalent to:
   * void(*handler)(int, siginfo_t *, void*) = func2;
   * func1(func2);
   */
  return 0;
}
```

Something to note is that sometimes you will see `func2` and other times `&func2`, but these are both the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function pointer declared:

```
sa_sigaction_t handler;
```

You can call it like:

```
handler( ... );
```

The clue is in the brackets, really. `void (*sa_sigaction_t)` is different from `void *sa_sigaction_t` .